# SlimPHP Application not downloading File

Tags: php, http, browser, http-headers, slim

I am trying to dowload a file using SlimPHP and it doesn't seem to be working for me.

Here is the route I have made:

```
    $backendApp->post('/export', function ($request, $response, $args) {
        $emails = $this->orginization->exportEmails();
        $exportFile = $this->file->writeEmailExport($emails, 'AllEmails.csv');

        $fh = fopen($exportFile, "r");
        $stream = new \Slim\Http\Stream($fh);

        $response = $response->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream')
            ->withHeader('Content-Description', 'File Transfer')
            ->withHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="' . basename($exportFile) . '"')
            ->withHeader('Content-Length', filesize($exportFile))
            ->withBody($stream);

        return $response;
    });
```

I know for a fact that $exportFile is a valid PHP streaming resource as the contents of the file come back in the response, I just need to trigger the browser file download functionality for the user.

These are the headers that are present on the response:

```
Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection:close
Content-Description:File Transfer
Content-Disposition:attachment; filename="AllEmails.csv"
Content-Length:267
Content-Type:application/octet-stream
Expires:Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Host:localhost:8080
Pragma:no-cache
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.6.15
```

Does anything immediately standout that I am doing wrong here? I can see the contents of the file come back in the response tab so I know that I am getting the contents of the file, I just need the user to be prompted to download said file.

Comment: My download file code does not use the slim framework and my code is 3+ years old, so perhaps I should not comment, but I was just wondering - have you tried using `preg_replace("([^\w\s\d\-_~,;:\[\]\(\].]|[\.]{2,})", '', $exportFile)` and `filter_var($dl_file, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL)` where `$dl_file` is the result of preg_replace to remove any invalid characters? If you are getting the contents of the file....I'm not entirely sure this would help, just a thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's related to however you are calling this as this code works:

```
$app = new \Slim\App($config);

$app->get("/", function ($request, $response, $args) {

    $response->write(
        <<<EOT
<form method="POST" action="/export">
<input type="submit" value="Download">
</form>
EOT
    );

    return $response;
});

$app->post('/export', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    $exportFile = __DIR__ . '/../test_file.txt';

    $fh = fopen($exportFile, "r");
    $stream = new \Slim\Http\Stream($fh);

    $response = $response->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream')
        ->withHeader('Content-Description', 'File Transfer')
        ->withHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="' . basename($exportFile) . '"')
        ->withHeader('Content-Length', filesize($exportFile))
        ->withBody($stream);

    return $response;
});
```

You say that you can see information in the response tab. Does this mean that you're triggering this via JavaScript? If so, then the browser will send the file back to the JS rather than to the user. If you want the file download dialog to appear, then provide a form (as you want a POST) with a button on it for the user to click.

Comment: Ahhh yes your comment about calling the route via Javascript was spot on. Thank you